# Jboss Activemq 6.1.0 queue message processing slows down after 10000 messages

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic

Below is the configuration:

- 2 JBoss application nodes
- 5 listeners on the application node with 50 threads each, supports
  clustering and is set up as active-active listener, so they run on
  both app nodes
- The listener simply gets the message and logs the information into
  database
- 50000 messages are posted into ActiveMQ using JMeter.

Here is the observation on first execution:

- Total 50000 messages are consumed in approx 22 mins.
- first 0-10000 messages consumed in 1 min approx
- 10000-20000 messages consumed in 2 mins approx
- 20000-30000 messages consumed in 4 mins approx
- 30000-40000 messages consumed in 6 mins approx
- 40000-50000 messages consumed in 8 mins

So we see the message consumption time is increasing with increasing number of messages.

Second execution without restarting any of the servers:

- 50000 messages consumed in 53 mins approx!

> But after deleting data folder of activemq and restarting activemq,
>   performance again improves but degrades as more data enters the queue!

I tried multiple configuration in activemq.xml, but no success...

Anybody faced similar issue, and got any solution ? Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Are any messages failing to be consumed?  KahaDB (I assume that's what you're using, though you really need to specify that in your question) will keep the entire file if a single message in it remains unconsumed (hint: in the DLQ = unconsumed), so that might explain at least some of the slowdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

50000 messages in > 20 mins seems very low performance.

Following configuration works well for me (these are just pointers. You may already have tried some of these but see if it works for you)

1) Server and queue/topic policy entry

```
// server
server.setDedicatedTaskRunner(false)
// queue policy entry
policyEntry.setMemoryLimit(queueMemoryLimit); // 32mb
policyEntry.setOptimizedDispatch(true);
policyEntry.setLazyDispatch(true); 
policyEntry.setReduceMemoryFootprint(true);
policyEntry.setProducerFlowControl(true);
policyEntry.setPendingQueuePolicy(new StorePendingQueueMessageStoragePolicy());
```

2) If you are using `KahaDB` for persistence then use per destination adapter (`MultiKahaDBPersistenceAdapter`). This keeps the storage folders separate for each destination and reduces synchronization efforts. Also if you do not worry about abrupt server restarts (due to any technical reason) then you can reduce then disk sync efforts by

```
kahaDBPersistenceAdapter.setEnableJournalDiskSyncs(false);
```

3) Try increasing the memory usage, temp and storage disk usage values at server level.

4) If possible increase prefetchSize in prefetch policy. This will improve performance but also increases the memory footprint of consumers.

5) If possible use transactions in consumers. This will help to reduce the message acknowledgement handling and disk sync efforts by server.

Comment: Will try out all these options and see if anything solves the issue...Thanks.

Comment: Also what is the time i can expect for 50000 messages to be processed, with the current configuration, assuming the listener simply dumps some data into DB without any kind of processing?

Comment: It depends on your server, number of processors, memory etc. But 20 mins sounds slow to me as I usually see 200-300 msg/sec (quad core, 512mb memory for activemq)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar slowdowns in our production systems when pending message counts go high. If you're flooding the queues then the MQ process can't keep all the pending messages in memory, and has to go to disk to serve a message. Performance can fall off a cliff in these circumstances. Increase the memory given to the MQ server process.

Also looks as though the disk storage layout is not particularly efficient - perhaps having each message as a file in a single directory? This can make access time rise as traversing disk directory takes longer.

Answer (score 0):

Point 5 mentioned by @hemant1900 solved the problem :) Thanks.

> 5) If possible use transactions in consumers. This will help to reduce
>   the message acknowledgement handling and disk sync efforts by server.

The problem was in my code. I had not used transaction to persist the data in consumer, which is anyway bad programming..I know :(

But didn't expect that could have caused this issue.

Now 50000, messages are getting processed in less than 2 mins.